# Strange Name space error for not used namespace in asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I am getting strange error
"The type or namespace name 'ABC' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) in Asp mvc"

for the namespace which is not even used in the project. This "ABC" namespace has not used in the project still it is giving me this error. I have tried following

1. Clear Temp files.
2. Clear Visual studio temp files.
3. Deleted bin folder

**Note: I am only getting error on views which are inside Area. This area I have copied from different project, which have namespace which is giving me error.**

Here is screen shot of error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After wasting 1 day and I finally found my solution. Here is the what I have followed:

http://matthewwilliams.com/changing-namespace-for-an-mvc-project-in-visual-studio/

Wrong namespace is in 
Areas=>AreaName=>web.config file under this:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
```

I renamed bad namespaces to correct one and everything works fine.